# Putting 2 consecutive lines of same matching pattern into single line

Tags: perl

I want to parse this set of lines so that if get the same pattern like `**<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>**` in consecutive lines, it should print it in single with "," in between the two.

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
```

How can I do that in Perl?

Comment: People down-vote without specifying reason.

Comment: Post your work. I have deleted my solution as you haven't posted your work.

Answer (score 2):

With lookaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<'EOS';
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
EOS

$str =~ s/(?<=<yagyavalkbhatt\@yahoo.com>)\s+(?=<yagyavalkbhatt\@yahoo.com>)/,/g;
print $str;
```

Output:

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                 (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                         <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                 (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                         <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: Thanks flesk
But the problem is the output u are showing can differ if second consecutive email id is diffrent and sorry but i dont need the above values besides those email adresses

Comment: @yagyavalkbhatt: Are you saying you just want to extract all email adresses from a string? If it's a fair assumption that all email adresses are enclosed within `<` and `>` `my @emails = $str =~ /<([^<\@]+\@[^>]+)>/g;` should accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks Flesk
How to print a text file content inside a EOS or $_

Comment: @yagyavalkbhatt: If your content is in a text file you should read from a file handle: `open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "Oops: $!\n";while (<$fh>) {# extract email addresses from $_}`