# Perl put lines in a file in to a single file

Tags: linux, perl

I have a file called mail.txt in which lines are printed like below ,i want to put all those lines in to one single line like

Thanks

---

This is the input

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

This is the output

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>

q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred), <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877118/putting-2-consecutive-lines-of-same-matching-pattern-into-single-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why don't you just do it?

```
open(my $fh, "<", $input_filename);

my @lines = map { chomp; $_} <$fh>; #1

close $fh;

open(my $out, ">", $output_filename);

print $out join "", @lines; # or maybe a different separator, like ","

close $out;

#that's it
```

Note: if you want to get rid of the extra spaces at the beginnings and ends of input lines, you can replace line `#1` by

```
my @lines = map { s/\s+$//; s/^\s+//; $_} <$fh>;
```

Comment: Thanks jpalecek 
I tried the code submitted by you it didnt worked,its giving me the same file as before.

Comment: @yagyavalkbhatt: Yeah, I always forget stripping the line terminator. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks jpaleck
Thanks alot it worked perfectly but the only thing which i want is output to be like stated in the post

currently i am getting q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>,q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred), <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyav@yahoo.com>


I want \n at the end of > of laas email id

Comment: This solution outputs just concatenates the records in the file into a single line of text. It is nothing like the required output as shown in the question.

Comment: @Borodin: quoting the question: "i want to put all those lines in to one single line". If the OP wants something else, he should describe it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to introduce comma separators between joined lines and blank lines between records.

The code below treats lines with leading whitespace as being continuation lines. We strip leading and trailing whitespace and glue records together.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

*ARGV = *DATA;  # for demo only

my $line;
while (<>) {
  s/\s+$//;

  if (s/^\s+//) {
    $line .= "," . $_;
    next;
  }
  else {
    print $line, "\n\n" if defined $line;
    $line = $_;
  }
}

print $line, "\n" if defined $line;

__DATA__
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

Output:

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>

q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

The code above contains its own input. To use it on real data, remote the line with the `# for demo only` comment and the entire `__DATA__` section. Then you can run it as in

```
$ join-lines mail-log
```

or even

```
$ join-lines mail-log1 mail-log2 mail-log3
```

To redirect the standard output to the file `oneline.log`, run it as

```
$ join-lines mail-log >oneline.log
```

Comment: Thanks Greg thanks for your answer but i need to know how to put its output in a file.

Comment: @YagyavalkBhatt I recommend using redirection for this, as it’s the most flexible approach. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it is safe to assume that lines that start with whitespace are continuation lines, this can be done very simply by accumulating each composite record in a global string variable.

This program does what is required. The `s/^\s+//` statement both removes leading whitespace and determines whether the line is a continuation line.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = '';

while (<DATA>) {
  s/\s+\z//;
  if (s/^\s+//) {
    $line .= ','.$_;
  }
  else {
    print $line, "\n" if $line;
    $line = $_;
  }
}
print $line, "\n";

__DATA__
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
                                             <yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

**output**

```
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<ygyalkatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>,(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred),<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>,<yagyav@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin thanks for your answer but i need to know how to put its output in a file.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
my $line;
my $i = 0;
open (FILE1, "<input.txt") or die "Can't find file";       
open (FILE2, ">output.txt") or die $!;

while($line = <FILE1>){

    if ($line =~ /<Mailer-daemon>/) 
    {
        #If it contains <Mailer-daemon> it retains its normal formatting./\

        print FILE2 substr($line, 0 , $line.length()-1); #chops off newline character
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
        $line =~ s/\s//g; #this regex kills all whitespace...not sutiable for mailer daemon lines.
        print FILE2 $line;
        $i++;
    }

    if ($i == 4)
    {
        #Every 4th line you want two newline characters as per sample output
         print FILE2 "\n\n";
         $i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        #comma seperator between non fourth-line parts
         print FILE2 ", "
    }
}

close FILE1;
close FILE2;
```

This is very specific to input and output similar to what you gave. I would not run this if the format changed even slightly.